# (Weird) - ORA-12516 - TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack [with only one active connection]

Tags: spring, oracle

I am trying to run a Spring loader. That loader will take the data from the csv file and insert into oracle database. It starts well, after processing some records, i am getting the below error.

'ORA-12516 - TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack'

Note : No other jobs were running at that time. Only this job was running.

```
processes -- 45 (CURRENT_UTILIZATION) -- 51 (MAX_UTILIZATION)
sessions -- 53 (CURRENT_UTILIZATION) -- 61 (MAX_UTILIZATION)

show parameter processes (processes - integer - 300)
show parameter session (sessions - integer - 480)
```

The thing is, the same batch program is running fine in another server, which has the same set of above configurations.

Since its a new server, anything i am missing in regards to oracle.? Can someone guide.

Comment: Can you show the connection details(tns alias or connection string) and the output of lsnrctl status and lsnrctl services?

Comment: i am having multiple instance running that server. whenever i put lsnrctl services, its point to default 1521 port, which i am not using..                                          Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error....I do have a defined port..say...3201 for database.

Comment: As i said, i do have multiple instances, i am seeing the below in tnsnames.ora file. The below service ''NEWS' is mine and i am using it. Do i need to clean up all the other descriptions and have only NEWS related port.?   NEWS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername)(PORT = 3200))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername)(PORT = 3201))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername)(PORT = 3207))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = NEWS)
    )
  )

Comment: Let’s first simplify things and have one listener running on the default port. With oracle to reach a database you address it by port (all databases and instances on a host can use the same listener and the same port) and a service name. After that make a single tns alias that has one address and point it to your listener port(1521) remove the other addresses.